# I only have the print BINGO , Now I have to put a randomizer number will go to each col row

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

This is the Main Code. I do need a Randomizer number and without duplication to create a table of number in my BINGO Board

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BingoCardGen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] table = new string[5, 5];
            
            printboard(table);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

this code will only print the BINGO board. My missing code is generate a random number  and  place it to the right column and cell
without duplication of number

```
        static void printboard(string[,] table)
        {
            int i, j;
            string[] headings = { "B", "I", "N", "G", "O" };
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}      ", headings[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 2 && j == 2)
                        Console.Write("X      ");
                    else
                        Console.Write("{0}     ", table[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing : Generate a number to be put in the bingo card. and put it in the right place (column , cell)

I have : Generating Bingo Card 
           : Duplication Check because it's given

Comment: This is BINGO generator.

Comment: If you need to add information to your question you can click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69074195/edit) link in the bottom-left of your question.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Most notably: this is an entire task that hasn't been started, whereas StackOverflow is for specific problems.

Comment: @Robson , I'm so sorry. I'm having a hard time to put a random integer into the exact column and cell of BINGO.

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: Do you know how to generate a random number? Do you know how to assign a value to an element of an array?

Comment: I know how to generate a random number. But i dont know how to place it right

Right now i have this Output

'B  I  N G O
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x
x  x  X  x  x
x  x  x   x x
x  x  x   x x'

the small x , where the Random generate number is place .
 i dont know how to do that. But i do know how to generate a random number.

I dont know also how to assign a value to an element of an array.

Comment: That's good about the random numbers. I'll write you a function to do this.

Comment: If you want to assign a value to the first item in your array, you would do `table[0, 0] = "z"` The zeroes are the row/column of the array, so you can adjust those to place items in other parts of the array.

Comment: @Robson I have the code already, but the Generating randoms numbers is not using the method i want like for Example rnd.Next(1, 20)) . You want to see it ? and change into the method required.

Comment: I've added an answer below, which creates the bingo card.

Comment: @Robson Sir can u make it  B =(1,15 ) I = (16,30) N = (31, 45) G = (46,60) O = (61,75) Thats the only number in each letter allowed. This will be the last and i will be fully understand.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot , Last question this can be able to generate multiple card in once? What will be the code added? @Robson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to generate a bingo card: (there's an explanation afterwards)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace BingoCardGen
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int BingoSpacing = 5;
        private const int BingoBallBuckets = 15;
        private const int BingoCardLength = 5;
        private const int BingoCardAmount = 3;

        private static Random random = new Random();

        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BingoCardAmount; i++)
            {
                var table = new string[BingoCardLength, BingoCardLength];
                PopulateBingoBoard(table);
                PrintBoard(table);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void PopulateBingoBoard(string[,] table)
        {            
            for (var col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
            {
                // generate all possible bingo ball numbers for this column
                var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1 + (col * BingoBallBuckets), BingoBallBuckets).ToList();

                // randomly place those numbers into the rows of this column
                for (var row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
                {
                    var chosenIndex = random.Next(allNumbers.Count);
                    table[row, col] = allNumbers[chosenIndex].ToString();
                    allNumbers.RemoveAt(chosenIndex);
                }
            }

            // middle cell is always free
            table[table.GetLength(0) / 2, table.GetLength(1) / 2] = "X";
        }

        private static void PrintBoard(string[,] table)
        {
            // print the title
            string[] headings = { "B", "I", "N", "G", "O" };
            for (var i = 0; i < headings.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(headings[i].PadRight(BingoSpacing));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            // print the numbers
            for (var i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(table[i, j].PadRight(BingoSpacing));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've done the following things:

```cs
private const int BingoSpacing = 5;
private const int BingoBallBuckets = 15;
private const int BingoCardLength = 5;
private const int BingoCardAmount = 3;
```

I've defined some numbers at the top of the code, because this makes them easy to change and it makes our code more readable/understandable.

```cs
private static void PopulateBingoBoard(string[,] table)
{            
    for (var col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
    {
        // generate all possible bingo ball numbers for this column
        var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1 + (col * BingoBallBuckets), BingoBallBuckets).ToList();

        // randomly place those numbers into the rows of this column
        for (var row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
        {
            var chosenIndex = random.Next(allNumbers.Count);
            table[row, col] = allNumbers[chosenIndex].ToString();
            allNumbers.RemoveAt(chosenIndex);
        }
    }

    // middle cell is always free
    table[table.GetLength(0) / 2, table.GetLength(1) / 2] = "X";
}
```

That's the new function. We send in the array and the function modifies that array.

For each column:

We use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to generate a list of the possible numbers for that column. For example, it will generate a list of `{ 1, 2, 3 ... 13, 14, 15 }` for the first column.

The code then loops through every cell in that column, selects a random bingo ball from the list, puts that bingo ball numbers into the table, then deletes that bingo ball from the list. This ensures that there are no duplicates, because a ball can never be selected twice.

```cs
Console.Write(table[i, j].PadRight(BingoSpacing));
```

I've added `PadRight` to all of the outputting. This ensures that everything lines up nicely. `PadRight` will add spaces to the end of a string, until that strings is our required length. So if we wanted a length of 6 and our string was `frog`, then output would be `frog`  .

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
```

Instead of `5` being hard-coded into the output loop, I've changed this to use the array length instead. This means the code would continue to work if the array length changed.

Example output:

```
B    I    N    G    O
1    30   37   49   61
15   16   35   53   75
12   29   X    58   68
4    28   39   51   70
10   24   34   47   64
```

Comment: I do appreciate what you did sir. I also get it but the B is range into (1,15 ) I = (16,30) N = (31, 45) G = (46,60) O = (61,75) Thats the only number in each letter allowed.

Comment: No worries, I can just modify it a little bit to do that. One moment...

Comment: That's done - I've updated the explanation as well.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot , Last question this can be able to generate multiple card in once? What will be the code added?

Comment: Yeah, you can put a loop in the `Main` function to do that. I've added the loop to the code above.

Comment: Thankyouu. U are so great at this. Do you have youtube channel so i can learn more?

Comment: You're very welcome - glad I could help. I don't have a (relevant) youtube channel, but good luck with your programming!